# Error on lottie-player src path > not working in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

When I insert the `<lottie-player>` inside my Vue.js code and the animation is from the lottiefiles’ website: it’s working fine. But if my animation.json is from my public file, I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the ‘responseText’ property from ‘XMLHttpRequest’: The value is only accessible if the object’s ‘responseType’ is ‘’ or ‘text’ (was ‘json’).
```

My code looks like this:

```html
<v-skeleton-loader width="100%" type="image">
  <lottie-player
    src="../public/image/animations/myanimation.json"
    background="transparent"
    style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" 
    speed="1"
    autoplay
  ></lottie-player>
</v-skeleton-loader>
```

Can’t figure out why. Does someone has the solution ?

Comment: The error suggests it needs text instead of JSON

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently.

SO I switched to a different npm package, where I also had similar problem but solved it - In the documentation it states you need to place your json file within the public folder.

The public folder is usually where your default favicon and index.html files reside. Thus you could try it first on this component which should look as follows.

```
<lottie-player
    src="image/animations/myanimation.json"
    background="transparent"
    style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" 
    speed="1"
    autoplay
  ></lottie-player>
```

Otherwise I would advice looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-vuejs